# Qt equivalent function for glutswapbuffers()

Tags: qt, function

Please tell me what is the Qt equivalent function for glutswapbuffers()..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QGLContext::swapBuffers()
```

or, if you're working with a widget:

```
QGLWidget::swapBuffers()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably [QGLWidget::swapBuffers](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qglwidget.html#swapBuffers).  Totally untested.